# Copy features from a SQLite multipolygon to SQLite polygon layer

Tags: qgis, sqlite, copy, multipart

I need to copy features from a multipolygon layer that contains multipart features into a polygon layer in SQLite in QGIS. I know I can run the "Multiparts to Singleparts" algorithm and simply copy and paste but this is something I'm going to have to do a lot and was wondering if there is some easier way.

Comment: SpatiaLite lacks some core functions due to SQLites lack of array support, and that includes any form of geometry dumping (collections, points etc.). I would go with running ogr2ogr in script, either in bash/shell or e.g. Python or whatever lamguage GDAL/OGR is portet to/has bindings for that you can write comfortably.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to code. What I want is to convert multipolygon features from multipart to single part in layer A. Copy and paste those features into a polygon layer B and then save off layer B as a GeoJSON. Which is a bit of a hassle to do manually every time.